# Need help with a MS-SQL query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

What I am trying to accomplish is to get the ID column from @temp2 to correspond to both intA and intB columns from @temp1
The end result output I would hope to see would look something like:

```
intA    intB    'asset1'    'asset2'    'name1' 'name2'

1   1   108 108 Cash    Cash

1   2   108 109 Cash    Commodities

1   3   108 138 Cash    Stock
.
.
.

2   5   109 111 Commodities Equity
```

Here is some sample data I am working with:

```
declare @temp1 table
(
    intA    int,
    intB    int
)
insert @temp1
select 1,1 union all
select 1,2 union all
select 1,3 union all
select 1,4 union all
select 1,5 union all
select 2,1 union all
select 2,2 union all
select 2,3 union all
select 2,4 union all
select 2,5

select * from @temp1
declare @temp2 table
(
    oneup   int,
    id  int,
    name    varchar(30)
)
insert @temp2
select 1,108,'Cash' union all
select 2,109,'Commodities' union all
select 3,138,'Stock' union all
select 4,110,'Bonds' union all
select 5,111,'Equity'

select * from @temp2

select t1.*,t2.* from @temp1 t1
inner join @temp2 t2
on t1.intA = t2.oneup
```

I can't get the join to work right to give me an output like I expect.
Using SQL2008

thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join to `@temp2` twice, once for `intA` and once for `intB`.

```
select t1.intA, t1.intB, 
       t2a.id as asset1,  t2b.id as asset2, 
       t2a.name as name1, t2b.name as name2
    from @temp1 t1
        inner join @temp2 t2a
            on t1.intA = t2a.oneup
        inner join @temp2 t2b
            on t1.intB = t2b.oneup
```

Comment: perfect!  Exactly what I was looking for.  Didn't think about using a 2nd join.  Thanks!